# on conflict do update

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to know if there's a workaround for this. I need to insert Student Balance data into a table. The source data have duplicate values for student_id, school_id and campus_name. My StudentBalance model in Django have Class Meta of:

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            "school",
            "student_id",
            "campus_name"
        )
```

Searched online and found this magical tool called ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. I played around with it, made it work but there's a problem. The balance data is not being updated which is because it's not in class Meta with unique_together. I would like to know if there's a way to update the data in Student Balance column without adding it to the class Meta?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Could you share the code you're using which does `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`?  Also, where do you want to have this balance data?  I'm not personally a Django expert, but I think you have to have it in a class somewhere ... otherwise, I would think you don't have any "column" to update in the first place, right?

Comment: Hi there, here's the code of the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`

`ON CONFLICT (school_system_id,
                                      student_id,
                                      campus_name
                                      ) DO UPDATE
                              SET school_system_id = excluded.school_system_id,
                                  student_id = excluded.student_id,
                                  campus_name = excluded.campus_name`

The will be saved in StudBalance model in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to add the column inside the ON CONFLICT parenthesis. I thought, only the columns that have duplicate data are the inside the parenthesis.

```
ON CONFLICT (school_system_id, student_id, campus_name ) DO UPDATE 
SET school_system_id = excluded.school_system_id, 
    student_id = excluded.student_id, 
    campus_name = excluded.campus_name,
    balance = excluded.balance
```

Comment: Hi Tango!  Is this the answer to your question, or are you clarifying your question?  If this is just more information to clarify your question, then you should delete this and then edit your original question to contain this information instead of posting it as an answer.  Otherwise, if this is actually the answer, you should accept it as the answer to close the question.

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is the answer. It says I can accept my own answer tomorrow.